# Asterisk call transfer on DAHDI channells

Tags: asterisk, pbx, elastix

[image]

All channels on Asterisk configured as DAHDI channels.After customer make payment I want to transfer the customer to the representative who interact customer before.

I try to make it by Dial() command. This is the dialplan

```
exten => s,1,Set(TRFNUM=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => s,2,Set(TRFNAME=${CALLERID(name)})
exten => s,3,AGI(agi://192.168.7.20/customivr)
exten => s,4,Dial(DAHDI/1/${TRFNUM}&DAHDI/2/${TRFNUM}&DAHDI/3/${TRFNUM}&DAHDI/4/${TRFNUM}&DAHDI/5/${TRFNUM}&DAHDI/6/${TRFNUM}&DAHDI/7/${TRFNUM}&DAHDI/8/${TRFNUM},30)
exten => s,5,Hangup
```

For example: Call comes to DAHDI/1 after the payment DAHDI/1 dial all channels one them Answer the others Hangup. DAHDI/1 bridge call by with DAHDI/2. However, although Customer and representative close phones, Channels do not Hangup. They stay Busy.

Where do i make mistake. I should hangup call channels or find another way to transfer.

Comment: "Channel not hangup" looks like card not setup correctly. Sorry, you not provided enought info for answer exactly.

Comment: @arheops what info do you want ? I can provide any info you want

Comment: Dial plan stacked in the 4 line. After dial it does not go to 5th step (Hangup)

Comment: You need check state of channels when it "not go to 5-th step". Also you have fix you tone detections on dahdi.

Comment: @arheops you are right, thank you. I hava a problem with tone detection. I test it using another PBX it works fine with asterisk. But I can not configure this PBX for asterisk tone detection. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Read docs about dahdi or hire expert. I can't put all posible issues here,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be configured correctly, 
I think your AGI script hangup the call when he finishes his work, 
It can happen if you have $agi>hangup in the end, 
or if you make any outputs in the scripts (echo, print_r, etc...),
even empty spaces output can cause this behavior,

another thing you can try is make the Dial command from the agi itself using:
agi->exec("Dial","options");